# NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, noclassdeffounderror, throwable

I'm using gradle as the JavaFX plugin.
Everything works perfectly even after building and runnig the excecutable at *distribution/*, except with one class: `CloseableHttpClient`

For several purposes I create the following object like this:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

Running the program in the IDE is no problem, everything works fine. But if I build and try to run the .exe-File I get the following `Throwable`-StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:955)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
    at ch.itcb.tools.lom.util.JsonSimpleUtil.http(JsonSimpleUtil.java:29)...
```

I really don't understand that. How can it be that just this class doesn't get found, but all my other classes do?

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply from: 'javafx.plugin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '0.1'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'LogoffManager',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'

    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'



    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

Please write a comment if you need more information. Thx.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file.

Comment: @Opal done. still found no solution :/

Comment: Is the apache jar in the distribution? Does it contain the missing class?

Comment: @JensSchauder yes it does. can't believe it by myself.

Comment: No further help? Struggling still with the same problem..

Comment: Did you find a solution? would you share it? tnks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

it's a good question, which I came across just now while researching examples of the many ways Java developers can end up with class path fun :-)

I started with a minimal version of your build.gradle (including only what's directly relevant), specifically:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.oliverlockwood.Main'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
}
```

My 'Main' class, in this context, uses your code example, i.e.:

```
package com.oliverlockwood;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    }
}
```

At this stage, I can run `gradle clean build` followed by `java -jar build/libs/33106520.jar` (my project was named after this StackOverflow question) and I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClients
    at com.oliverlockwood.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

This is subtly different from your error, but before we dig and reproduce that, let me emphasise something: both this error and the one you're seeing are caused at runtime when the classloader is unable to find a class that it needs.  There's quite a good blog post [here](http://techblog.bozho.net/runtime-classpath-vs-compile-time-classpath/) with some more details about the difference between compile-time classpath and runtime classpaths.

If I run `gradle dependencies` I can see the runtime dependencies for my project:

```
runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1
     +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3
     +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
```

I added these manually one-by-one to my runtime classpath.  (For the record, this isn't generally considered good practice; but for the sake of the experiment, I copied these jars to my `build/libs` folder and ran with `java -cp build/libs/33106520.jar:build/libs/* com.oliverlockwood.Main`.  Interestingly enough, this wasn't able to reproduce your exact problem.  To recap:

- Without `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` available at runtime, then we fail because the `HttpClients` jar is not found.
- With `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1` available at runtime, then your problem does not manifest - and I note that the class your build fails to find (`org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory`) is *part of this same Apache library*, which is very suspicious indeed.

My suspicion is then that your runtime classpath contains a *different version* of the Apache httpclient library.  Since there's a whole lotta versions out there, I'm not going to test every single combination, so I will instead leave you with the following advice.

1. If you want to fully understand the root cause of your issue, then identify *exactly* which jars (including their versions) are present in your error-case runtime classpath, including any jars that are packaged inside yours if you're creating a fat jar (more on this in point 3).  It'd be great if you shared these details here; root cause analysis usually helps everyone to understand better :-)
2. Where possible, avoid using dependencies in the manner of `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])`.  Managed dependencies based on a repository such as Maven or JCenter are much easier to work with consistently than dependencies in a random directory.  If these are internal libraries that you don't want to publish to an open-source artifact repository, then it may be worth setting up a local Nexus instance or similar.
3. Consider producing a "fat jar" instead of a "thin jar" - this means that all runtime dependencies are packaged in the jar that you build.  There's a good [Shadow plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) that I'd recommend - with this in place in my `build.gradle`, and running `gradle clean shadow`, I was able to run `java -jar` just fine without needing to manually add anything to my classpath.

Comment: I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup`. I kept looking for presence of this class inside Apache Http JARs (httpclient, httpcore) under `Maven Dependencies` in Eclipse and did not find them. Realized that maven chose to resolve some other version of `httpcore` from parent POM instead of `httpcore` version which is a direct dependency of `httpclient`.Had to give an explicit `httpcore` version which matches the same version as that of version of direct dependency of `httpclient`.

Comment: At recent gradle versions, `gradle dependencies` produces a message: `A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.` And `gradle build --scan` produces a publically browsable report with deps that you can delete when completed.

Comment: Thank you for the hint on deps - I have a cosmo zoo of versions causing `NoClassDef*`.

Comment: Switching in IJ gradle setting to buildusing IJ did the trick for now

Answer (score 0):

For Spring boot users, this can be solved with one line of code. I am using `Gradle/Kotlin`, so:

> `id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.5"`

inside the `plugins {}` section of your build.gradle.kts

For more information visit the [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/).

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I turned on my InteliJ after 3 months, got some runtime errors like noclassdeffounderror. I have to *** refresh gradle ***, then the errors are gone.

Comment: how does one refresh gradle?