# NoClassDefFoundError when using Guava classes even though Guava is included in Gradle build file and on classpath

Tags: java, gradle, guava

When I build my Guava dependent project with Gradle using:

```
//build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '22.0'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.3' //Tried 3.1 - 4.0.1 
    distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}
```

I get the following runtime error when running the project in Intellij:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multiset
```

The libraries are definitely in the classpath and I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have solved this problem by switching to an older Gradle version (3.1, 3.2, 3.3 all work).

Therefore, I believe the problem lies with Gradle 3.4+ (3.4, 3.5.1, 4.0 and 4.0.1) all of which I have tried and received the NoClassDefFoundError.

There is no mention of a Gradle version required in the [Guava documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild)

Is Guava incompatible with newer versions of Gradle?

Comment: What Java version are you compiling to? If Java 7 then chances are you need to downgrade guava to version 20.0.

Comment: I am using Java 8.  I have also determined that Gradle 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3 work, but Gradle 3.4+ all give me the same NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Try again with for instance  `gradle clean test --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: Tried `gradlew clean test --refresh-dependencies` (I am using a gradle wrapper) and received the same results for <=3.3 working and >3.3 NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Could you show me your `build.gradle`? Just edit your question.

Comment: I would guess most likely your classpath for compile time is different than classpath for runtime - would you be able to print your classpath in code and check if guava is there?

Comment: You get this exception when doing what? Be precise.

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz You are right!  When I print out my classpath at runtime Guava is there when I build with Gradle 3.3 but it disappears with newer versions of Gradle.  Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: You get this exception when doing what? Be precise.

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz yep the classpath.  I can't figure out what is making Guava disappear with newer Gradle versions.  It is still noticed as a dependency and is found at compile time, but missing at runtime.

Comment: @JBNizet Edited the original question to answer yours.  Runtime error when running project with Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind such behavior lies in your classpath. Compile time classpath is different than classpath for runtime. You pass guava to `javac` but you don't have it available at runtime.

Very good explanation of quite a similar issue is here: [NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106520/noclassdeffounderror-at-runtime-with-gradle).  I can't reproduce this issue locally.  Consider going to your gradle cache and remove everything.

Comment: Any idea how this could be happen with changing Gradle versions?

Comment: I see you edited your question, I am trying to figure it out. It's strange, try adding sth like this:
`sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath`
It should not be required at all though.

Comment: I tried the link and your suggestion and neither have worked. I may post another question because now the parameters are more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being with the version of Intellij I was using (2016.3.1)

Once I updated Intellij to 2016.3.7 the project runs fine with all versions of Gradle.